# Disposable Temporary Email with attachment download API support

Tags: ios, email

I am working on an application that uses [guerrillamail](https://www.guerrillamail.com/) to get temporary email and then I use its given API's to get the contents of emails sent to this id. What I am not able to achieve is that if email contains attachment how can I download it using API or parse the MIME using a mime parser library if I have the email source?

Or can you please recommend any alternative that provide API support to download attachments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to see if I could find an answer, so I made some code that seems to work:

```js
var template_content = $("#mail")[0].content;
var tep = $("#mail");

function getMail(id, mail_id) {
  $.get("https://api.guerrillamail.com/ajax.php?f=fetch_email&lang=en&sid_token=" + id + "&email_id=" + mail_id, function(mail) {
    console.log("Mail:");
    console.log(mail);
    template_content.querySelector('p:nth-of-type(1)').innerHTML = mail.mail_from;
    template_content.querySelector('p:nth-of-type(2)').innerHTML = mail.mail_subject;
    template_content.querySelector('p:nth-of-type(3)').innerHTML = mail.mail_body;
    if (mail.att == 0) {
      template_content.querySelector('span').innerHTML = "-none-";
    } else {
      var sp = template_content.querySelector('span');
      $.each(mail.att_info, function(l, att) {
        console.log(att);
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        console.log(a);
        var linkText = document.createTextNode(att.f + " [" + att.t + "]");
        a.appendChild(linkText);
        a.title = att.f + " [" + att.t + "]";
        a.href = "https://www.guerrillamail.com/inbox?get_att&lang=en&sid_token=" + id + "&email_id=" + mail.mail_id + "&part_id=" + att.p;
        sp.appendChild(a);
      });
    }
    var clone = document.importNode(template_content, true);
    document.querySelector('#mails').appendChild(clone);
  });
}

$.get("https://api.guerrillamail.com/ajax.php?f=get_email_address&lang=en", function(data) {
  var email = data.email_addr;
  var id = data.sid_token;
  $("#email_addr").text(email);
  $("#pane").show();

  $("#get").click(function() {
    $.get("https://api.guerrillamail.com/ajax.php?f=get_email_list&lang=en&sid_token=" + id + "&offset=0", function(data) {
      console.log(data.list);
      var tep = $("#mail");
      $.each(data.list, function(i, mail) {
        getMail(id, mail.mail_id)
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
p {
  display: inline
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="pane" style="display:none">
  <p>Send email with attachment to [<b id="email_addr">frefr</b>] and press the button:</p>
  <button id="get">Get mails!</button>
</div>

<br/>
<br/>

<div id="mails">

</div>


<template id="mail">
  <div>
    <h2>Mail</h2>
    Sender:
    <p>1</p>
    <br/>Subject:
    <p>2</p>
    <br/>Body:
    <br/>
    <hr/>
    <p>3</p>
    <br/>
    <hr/>Attachments:
    <br>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</template>
```

I can't find any info about the attachment stuff in [the documentation](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Qw5KQP1j57BPTDmms5nspe-QAjNEsNg8cQHpAAycYNM/edit?usp=sharing), but in my code I used the "normal" attachment link, and it seems to work:

```
https://www.guerrillamail.com/inbox?get_att&lang=en&sid_token={sid_token}&email_id={email_id}&part_id={part_id}";
```

Look at my example code to see how to use it.

You seem to have most of the code done on the iPhone side, basically you just have to add a call to the `get_att` url with the `att parameters` from the `fetch_email`.

Answer (score 0):

Temp Mail seems to [have an API that suits your needs](https://market.mashape.com/Privatix/temp-mail#get-message-attachments). You can retrieve an email attachment with:

```
https://privatix-temp-mail-v1.p.mashape.com/request/attachments/id/{md5}/
```

It gives you back a JSON array of all the attachment.